# Cannot get HTML/Javascript page to draw fraction using Canvas tag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to get the following single HTML5 page with embedded Javascript to draw a fraction of a circle dependent upon the numerator and dominator chosen.

The code was suggested by @Vanojx1 but, my post was closed because it was not 'specific' enough, and, I just want some help understanding what I am doing wrong please:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="Fraction Learning app for Children">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var pi = Math.PI;


        document.getElementById("draw").addEventListener("click", function () {
            var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
            var den = document.getElementById("den").value;
            var rad = 2 / den * num * pi;
            var cx = 250;
            var cy = 250;

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);

            ctx.arc(cx, cy, 220, 1.5 * pi, 1.5 * pi + rad);

            ctx.lineTo(cx, cy);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();

        });
    </script>
    <title>Fractions Fun</title>
</head>

<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<br>
<input type="number" id="num" /> /
<input type="number" id="den" />
<br>
<button id="draw">
    DRAW
</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: looks like it's working fine, unless you are intending for it to do something different? http://jsbin.com/kecoyeyavu/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is rendered in the order that it appears in the DOM (that includes `script` blocks).  Therefore the script block will be run before `draw` is rendered.  As `draw` does not exist the script fails to add the click handler.

Putting the code in a function and call it using the `body`'s `onload` event would allow the click handler to be added.  See below -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="Fraction Learning app for Children">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var pi = Math.PI;
      document.getElementById("draw").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
        var den = document.getElementById("den").value;
        var rad = 2 / den * num * pi;
        var cx = 250;
        var cy = 250;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);

        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 220, 1.5 * pi, 1.5 * pi + rad);

        ctx.lineTo(cx, cy);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

      });
    }
  </script>
  <title>Fractions Fun</title>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="num" />/
  <input type="number" id="den" />
  <br>
  <button id="draw">
    DRAW
  </button>
</body>
```

Another method I've seen used is to put the `script` tag at the end of the document (although I'm not sure if it's considered best practice and I don't use it myself) -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="Fraction Learning app for Children">

  <title>Fractions Fun</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="num" />/
  <input type="number" id="den" />
  <br>
  <button id="draw">
    DRAW
  </button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var pi = Math.PI;
    document.getElementById("draw").addEventListener("click", function() {
      var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
      var den = document.getElementById("den").value;
      var rad = 2 / den * num * pi;
      var cx = 250;
      var cy = 250;

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);

      ctx.arc(cx, cy, 220, 1.5 * pi, 1.5 * pi + rad);

      ctx.lineTo(cx, cy);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();

    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that has worked, and, makes perfect sense!  Thank you also to @Vanojx1 for the original code.  Terrific!